# In Jmeter How can I use a captured regex variable as part of a file name?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm having some difficulty using a variable containing a regex capture as part of the file name in a 'Save Response to a file' listener. I am able to use the captured variable in an if controller successfully. But it is not happy when I use it in the file prefix section of the 'Save Response to a file' listener.

This is the JSON I am performing the regex on

```
"command":"ARCHIVE_FILE"
```

This is the regex

```
Reference Name:     command
Regular Expression: "command":"(.+?)"
Template:           $1$
Match No.           1
Default Value:      COMMAND_NOT_FOUND
```

I can successfully use the captured variable in an 'If Controller'. Although I must admit, I am a bit confused by the required double quotes. (I have tried without any double quotes but the if condition does not trigger)

```
If Controller
Condition:     "${command}"=="ARCHIVE_FILE"
```

So like I said, I have validated that the above works. But when I try to use the captured variable as part of the file name prefix in 'Save Response to a file', it saves the file literally as '${command}'. Not as the value stored in the variable.

```
Filename prefix: d:\tmp\${command}
```

Suspecting that my issue with this has something to do with the quotes, I then tried this as an experiment.

```
Filename prefix: d:\tmp\"${command}"
```

This did give me the value captured in the variable, but it was book-ended in double quotes and jmeter was not at all happy with that.

> **jmeter.reporters.ResultSaver: Error creating sample file for Client
>   Download Start java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   D:\apache-jmeter-2.9\tmp\client\"ARCHIVE_FILE" (The filename,
>   directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)**

Any help appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

**1.** double back-slashes in Filename prefix field:

```
d:\\tmp\\${command}
```

because a single backslash in this case will be taken as 'escape' character and variable will be not expanded to its value;

or:

**2.** define `d:\tmp\` part elsewhere in the script as separate variable e.g. `${responsePath}` and replace `d:\tmp\` in Filename prefix field with this variable:

```
${responsePath}${command}
```

Both variants will work correctly but the 2nd one seems to be a bit more general.